# Mysql Error 1111: Invalid use of group function in an Update

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1111

I have an error in mysql code, I'm trying to make an update and I get error

Error :

> "Error 1111: Invalid use of group function"

could you help me know what's wrong with my code? I am a beginner in MySQL

```
UPDATE
p_portfolio p LEFT JOIN p_portfolio_cstm pc
    ON p.id = pc.id_c
LEFT JOIN p_portfolio_p_purchaser_projects_1_c ppp1
    ON p.id = ppp1.p_portfolio_p_purchaser_projects_1p_portfolio_ida
LEFT JOIN p_purchaser_projects pp
    ON pp.id = ppp1.p_portfolio_p_purchaser_projects_1p_purchaser_projects_idb
LEFT JOIN p_purchaser_projects_cstm ppc
    ON pp.id = ppc.id_c

SET
pc.requested_itc_value_c = SUM(ppc.estimated_itc_value_c)

WHERE p.id = '4e9c9ea3-0880-4dc1-1063-5cbf71bd93bb'
AND p.deleted = 0 AND ppp1.deleted = 0 AND pp.deleted = 0;
```

Comment: Posting a broken query without any explanation what you are trying to do will not help us help you.

Comment: Sorry Eric what I try to do is sum the rows of the column called estimated_itc_value_c from the table p_purchaser_projects_cstm, but for this I have to join with the tables that can be seen in Joins to associate all the lines that are summed with a certain ID and the result will be saved in requested_itc_value_c of the table p_portfolio_cstm

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE
p_portfolio p INNER JOIN

(SELECT SUM(ppc.estimated_itc_value_c) as estimated_itc_value,pc.id_c,ppp1.deleted as ppp1_deleted,pp.deleted as pp_deleted 
FROM p_portfolio_cstm pc
LEFT JOIN p_portfolio_p_purchaser_projects_1_c ppp1
    ON p.id = ppp1.p_portfolio_p_purchaser_projects_1p_portfolio_ida
LEFT JOIN p_purchaser_projects pp
    ON pp.id = ppp1.p_portfolio_p_purchaser_projects_1p_purchaser_projects_idb
LEFT JOIN p_purchaser_projects_cstm ppc
    ON pp.id = ppc.id_c
) t2 ON p.id = t2.id_c
SET
pc.requested_itc_value_c = t2.estimated_itc_value

WHERE p.id = '4e9c9ea3-0880-4dc1-1063-5cbf71bd93bb'
AND p.deleted = 0 AND t2.ppp1_deleted = 0 AND t2.pp_deleted = 0;
```

Comment: Hi, thank you I will try this on the other hand I tried to execute the following code and it works but I don't know if is the correct way and if this code will cause problems with my data or data base, can you help me to know if is another correct way?

Comment: UPDATE
p_portfolio_cstm AS x

SET
x.requested_itc_value_c = 
(
SELECT
SUM(ppc.estimated_itc_value_c)

FROM p_purchaser_projects pp INNER JOIN p_portfolio_p_purchaser_projects_1_c ppp1
 ON pp.id = ppp1.p_portfolio_p_purchaser_projects_1p_purchaser_projects_idb
INNER JOIN p_purchaser_projects_cstm ppc
 ON pp.id = ppc.id_c
 
WHERE ppp1.p_portfolio_p_purchaser_projects_1p_portfolio_ida = '4e9c9ea3-0880-4dc1-1063-5cbf71bd93bb'
AND ppp1.deleted = 0 AND pp.deleted = 0
)
WHERE x.id_c = '4e9c9ea3-0880-4dc1-1063-5cbf71bd93bb';

Comment: * I changed the LEFT JOIN for INNER JOIN

Comment: In both the cases MySQL going to create a `temp` table for whatever we have between `(SELECT ....)`. This won't affect your current structure.

Comment: Thank you a lot! you helped me so much.

Comment: I would really appreciate if you accept my answer if it worked for you. So other users comes here will get the solution :)